# shapeless filter a list of options

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am new to shapeless and try to tackle the following problem. I have tuples of different length with Option[(R[A], A)] as elements and would like to kind of filter the tuple so that it results only in Some. Notice that I don't have Some or None at compile time but only Option.
I think I have kind of a recursive problem but cannot describe it. I have something like the following in mind (where I have already converted the tuple into an HList:

```
def performFinalStep[A1](t: Tuple1[A1]) = ???
def performFinalStep[A1, A2](t: Tuple2[A1, A2]) = ???
...

def reduce[T <: HList, A <: HList](l: Option[(R[A], A)] :: T, acc: A) = {
  case h :: HNil => performFinalStep(toTuple(h :: acc))
  case h :: t => reduce(t, h :: acc) //does not work as it is not known if T's head is Option[(R[A], A)]
}

reduce((Option(R(1), 2), Option(R("S", "s"))).productElements, HNil)
```

There are two things I don't know, how do I turn an HList back into a tuple and how can I overcome the typing for T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shapeless converting case classes to HLists and vice versa can be done via `shapeless.Generic`. And in Scala `Tuple`s are case classes. But there is standard way

```
(1 :: "a" :: true :: HNil).tupled // (1,a,true)

import shapeless.ops.hlist.Tupler
def toTuple[L <: HList](l : L)(implicit tupler: Tupler[L]): tupler.Out = l.tupled
```

When you can't express something with a method you create a type class (I don't know your actual type instead of `Nothing`)

```
case class R[A](a: A)

trait Reduce[L <: HList, Acc <: HList] {
  def apply(l: L, acc: Acc): Nothing
}

object Reduce {
  implicit def singletonCase[A, Acc <: HList](implicit
    tupler: Tupler[Option[(R[A], A)] :: Acc]): Reduce[Option[(R[A], A)] :: HNil, Acc] =
    (l, acc) => l match {
      case h :: HNil => performFinalStep(toTuple(h :: acc))
    }

  implicit def notSingletonCase[H, T <: HList, Acc <: HList](implicit
    reduce: Reduce[T, H :: Acc]): Reduce[H :: T, Acc] =
    (l, acc) => l match {
      case h :: t => reduce(t, h :: acc)
    }
}

def reduce[L <: HList, Acc <: HList](l: L, acc: Acc)(implicit 
  r: Reduce[L, Acc]): Nothing  = r(l, acc)
```

Next trouble is

```
Error:(39, 27) overloaded method value performFinalStep with alternatives:
  [A1, A2](t: (A1, A2))Nothing <and>
  [A1](t: (A1,))Nothing
 cannot be applied to (tupler.Out)
        case h :: HNil => performFinalStep(toTuple(h :: acc))
```

You can try one more type class

```
trait PerformFinalStep[P <: Product] {
  def apply(t: P): Nothing
}

object PerformFinalStep {
  implicit def tuple1[A1]: PerformFinalStep[Tuple1[A1]] = t => ???
  implicit def tuple2[A1, A2]: PerformFinalStep[Tuple2[A1, A2]] = t => ???
  // ...
}

def performFinalStep[T <: Product](t: T)(implicit 
  pfs: PerformFinalStep[T]) = pfs(t)

trait Reduce[L <: HList, Acc <: HList] {
  def apply(l: L, acc: Acc): Nothing
}

object Reduce {
  implicit def singletonCase[A, Acc <: HList, P <: Product](implicit
    tupler: Tupler.Aux[Option[(R[A], A)] :: Acc, P],
    pfs: PerformFinalStep[P]): Reduce[Option[(R[A], A)] :: HNil, Acc] =
    (l, acc) => l match {
      case h :: HNil => performFinalStep(toTuple(h :: acc))
    }

  implicit def notSingletonCase[H, T <: HList, Acc <: HList](implicit
    reduce: Reduce[T, H :: Acc]): Reduce[H :: T, Acc] =
    (l, acc) => l match {
      case h :: t => reduce(t, h :: acc)
    }
}

def reduce[L <: HList, Acc <: HList](l: L, acc: Acc)(implicit 
  r: Reduce[L, Acc]): Nothing  = r(l, acc)
```

Now `reduce((Option(R(1), 2), Option(R("S"), "s")).productElements, HNil)` produces "could not find implicit value for parameter" but `implicitly[Reduce[Option[(R[Int], Int)] :: Option[(R[String], String)] :: HNil, HNil]]` compiles. If we substitute explicitly

```
reduce((Option(R(1), 2), Option(R("S"), "s")).productElements, HNil)(
  implicitly[Reduce[Option[(R[Int], Int)] :: Option[(R[String], String)] :: HNil, HNil]]
)
```

we'll have

```
Error:(52, 82) type mismatch;
 found   : Reduce[Option[(R[Int], Int)] :: Option[(R[String], String)] :: shapeless.HNil,shapeless.HNil]
 required: Reduce[Option[(R[Int], Int)] :: Option[(R[String], String)] :: shapeless.HNil,shapeless.HNil.type]
Note: shapeless.HNil >: shapeless.HNil.type, but trait Reduce is invariant in type Acc.
You may wish to define Acc as -Acc instead. (SLS 4.5)
  reduce((Option(R(1), 2), Option(R("S"), "s")).productElements, HNil)(implicitly[Reduce[Option[(R[Int], Int)] :: Option[(R[String], String)] :: HNil, HNil]])
```

So you should call it like

```
reduce((Option(R(1), 2), Option(R("S"), "s")).productElements, HNil : HNil)
```

Comment: Hm... I had something similar but it did not work out. It seemed that the compiler was not able to find a Reducer[T, H :: Acc] in notSingletonCase. I used Generic instead of Tupler. Is there a difference? I guess Generic uses Tupler inside, right?

Comment: @RobertStoll Maybe you meant that vice versa Tupler uses Generic. But actually it doesn't https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L783-L798 https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala#L131-L156

Comment: If you meant the code you've posted above then the difference is that pattern matching is performed at runtime, and type classes work at compile time (implicits resolution). Also you confused type parameters `A` and `Acc`.

Comment: The difference between `Tupler` and `Generic` here is that `def toTuple[L <: HList](l : L)(implicit tupler: Tupler[L]): tupler.Out = l.tupled` works just like `toTuple(1 :: "a" :: true :: HNil)` but for `def toTuple[P <: Product, L <: HList](l : L)(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[P, L]): P = generic.from(l)` you have to specify types `toTuple[(Int, String, Boolean), Int :: String :: Boolean :: HNil](1 :: "a" :: true :: HNil)`.

Comment: @RobertStoll Are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) Only the following import was missing: `import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple.productElements`