# Why the Scala compiler can provide implicit outside of object, but cannot inside?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

The title might be quite vague, but here is the code: https://github.com/amorfis/why-no-implicit

So there is a tool to transform `Map[String, Any]` to a simple case class. The tests pass and this piece of code illustrates what it is all about:

```
        case class TargetData(
          groupId: String,
          validForAnalysis: Boolean,
          applicationId: Int
        )

        val map = Map(
          "groupId" -> "123456712345",
          "applicationId" -> 31,
          "validForAnalysis" -> true
        )

        val transformed: TargetData = MapDecoder.to[TargetData](map).transform
```

This code works. It nicely creates the case class instance when provided the simple `map`

However, the `transform` method has to be called "outside" - just like in the example. When I try to move it to the `MapDecoder.to` method - the compiler complains about the missing implicit.

So I change the code in `MapDecoder.to` from this:

```
def to[A](map: Map[String, Any]) = new MapDecoderH[A](map)
```

to this:

```
def to[A](map: Map[String, Any]) = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform
```

and it stops working. Why is that? Why the implicit is provided in one case but not in the other? All that changes is that I want to call the `transform` method in other place to have `MapDecoder.to` returning the case class not some transformer.

UPDATE:

What if I want to implement `to[A]` method inside an object I want to transform? Let's call it `DataFrame`, and I want this code to work:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...
df.to[TargetData] // There is no apply called here
```

The problem is in such case there is nothing to pass to `apply`. It is also not feasible to call it with parens (`df.to[TargetData]()`) because then the compiler requires implicits in parens. Is it even possible to solve it without using macros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit can be provided when the compiler can unambiguously find a value in the current scope with matching type.

Outside `def to` compiler sees that you want `MapDecoder[TargetData]`.

Inside it sees `MapDecoder[A]` and have no reason to believe that `A =:= TargetData`.

In such situation you'd have to pass all the implicits as arguments of `to` method. From your code it seems it would have to be something like

```
def to[A, R <: HList](map: Map[String, Any])(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  transformer: MapDecoder[R]
) = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform
```

but it would break the ergonomy, since you'd have to add additional parameter which should be inferred but cannot - in Scala 2 you are passing all type arguments explicitly or none. There are ways to work around it like by splitting the type param application into 2 calls like this:

```
class Applier[A] {

  def apply[R <: HList](map: Map[String, Any])(implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    transformer: MapDecoder[R]
  ) = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform
}

def to[A] = new Applier[A]
```

which would be used as

```
MapDecoder.to[A](map)
```

desugared by compiler to

```
MapDecoder.to[A].apply[InferredR](map)(/*implicit*/gen, /*implicit*/transformer)
```

It would be very similar to  `MapDecoder.to[TargetData](map).transform` but through a trick it would look much nicer.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question. I guess there is no solution to the updated version without using macros?

Answer (score 3):

@MateuszKubuszok answered the question. I'll just make a couple of comments to his answer.

Adding implicit parameters

```
def to[A](map: Map[String, Any]) = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform

// ===>

def to[A, R <: HList](map: Map[String, Any])(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  transformer: MapDecoder[R]
) = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform
```

you postpone implicit resolution in `.transform` from "now" i.e. the definition site of `to` (where `A` is abstract) to "later" i.e. the call site of `to` (where `A` is `TargetData`). Resolving implicits "now" is incorrect since `LabelledGeneric[A]` doesn't exist for abstract `A`, only for case classes, sealed traits, and like them.

This is similar to the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt) `implicitly[A]` vs. `(implicit a: A)`.

Another way of postponing implicit resolution is inlining. In Scala 3 there are [inline methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/inline.html) for that along with [`summonInline`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/compiletime-ops.html#summoninline) used in them.

In Scala 2 inlining can be achieved with [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
// libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.13.10"
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def to[A](map: Map[String, Any]): Either[String, A] = macro toImpl[A]

def toImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(map: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"new MapDecoderH[${weakTypeOf[A]}]($map).transform"
}
```

@MateuszKubuszok's solution with [PartiallyApplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430151/how-to-derive-a-generic-aux-if-the-case-class-has-a-type-parameter-shapeless) pattern (`Applier`) seems to be easier (adding implicit parameters is more conventional way to postpone implicit resolution although there can be situations when you just can't add parameters to a method).

---

**Update:**

> What if I want to implement `to[A]` method inside an object I want to transform?

You can define `apply` with empty parameter list

```scala
// implicit class or a class/object where you want to implement method inside
implicit class MapOps(map: Map[String, Any]) {
  def as[A] = new Applier[A]

  class Applier[A] {
    def apply[R <: HList]()(implicit
      gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
      transformer: MapDecoder[R]
    ): Either[String, A] = new MapDecoderH[A](map).transform
  }
}
```

(I renamed extension method to `as` since `Map` already has `.to`)

and call it like `map.as[TargetData]()`.

Suppose you don't want to add `()` like with Spark-ish `df.to[TargetData]`. You can always define a custom type class. This is more flexible solution than a method (with or without PartiallyApplied trick)

[How to derive a Generic.Aux if the case class has a type parameter - Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430151/how-to-derive-a-generic-aux-if-the-case-class-has-a-type-parameter-shapeless)

```scala
// type class
trait As[A] {
  def as(map: Map[String, Any]): Either[String, A]
}
object As {
  // materilizer
  def apply[A: As]: As[A] = implicitly[As[A]]

  // instances of the type class
  implicit def makeAs[A, R <: HList](implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    transformer: MapDecoder[R]
  ): As[A] = new MapDecoderH[A](_).transform
}


implicit class MapOps(map: Map[String, Any]) {
  // "implement method inside an object to transform"
  def as[A: As]: Either[String, A] = As[A].as(map)
}
```

Now you can call the method without `()` like `map.as[TargetData]`.

So you don't actually need macros now. I just mentioned macros solution for general understanding your options and better explanation of what's going on.

Comment: So it was enough to add empty parens! Gosh! Thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364545/type-parameter-for-implicit-valued-method-in-scala-circe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425914/implicit-json-formatter-for-value-classes-in-scala